# How can I alter variables sent to a paragraph bundle template within a module?

Tags: theming

I need to preprocess the field values of a paragraph bundle to "send" additional variables 
to the template (paragraphs-item--xxxx--full.tpl.php). I want to avoid putting too much php logic into the paragraph template.

I am searching for something similiar to the node_view hook for a paragraph item. Is there a fitting mechanism or maybee a module providing such an hook?

Answer (score 12):

#### Drupal 7

I don't know if this will help you directly, but I found this code snippet on [DropBucket](http://dropbucket.org/node/7016) and it helped me do something similar:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_entity().
 */
function wwvs_slices_preprocess_entity(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['entity_type'] == 'paragraphs_item') {
    $edge = field_get_items('paragraphs_item', $variables['paragraphs_item'], 'field_edge');
    if ($edge && $edge[0]['value']) {
      $variables['classes_array'][] = 'slice--edge';
    }
  }
}
```

In my usecase I wanted to augment the paragraph entity with an ID using the url-safe version of the title field used in that paragraph. Here's my implementation:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_entity().
 */
function foo_preprocess_entity(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['entity_type'] == 'paragraphs_item') {
    if(isset($variables['elements']['pp_title']['#items'][0]['value'])){
      $title = $variables['elements']['pp_title']['#items'][0]['value'];
      $title = strtolower(drupal_clean_css_identifier($title));
      $variables['attributes_array']['id'] = $title;
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 6):

#### Drupal 8

In Drupal 8 you can use [`hook_preprocess_HOOK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {

}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_paragraph__TYPE(&$variables) {

}
```