# How to add css class to a field from a select list before rendering?

Tags: entities, theming

I have a select list which has the following values where the key values are the same name as the css class name.

List1:

- prim-blue|Blue
- prim-black|Black
- prim-orange|Orange

We also have a text field which is surrounded by the following div tag below. Before the page renders, we want to take the value from list1 and assign it as a class to the div tag. We need assistance in figuring out how to get this to work using a preprocess hook.

```
/*css*/
prim-blue {
   //some attribute
}
prim-black {
   //some attribute
}
prim-orange {
   //some attribute
}

/*field div tag */
<div id="target-element"> <h1> Some text values </h1> </div>
```

Desired results (when page renders):

**Assume list1 is set to Blue (key: prim-blue)

```
<div id="target-element" class="prim-blue"> <h1> Some text values </h1> </div>
```

Note (to provide more context):

**I am using the paragraph module** which a bundle that has a background color for list1 and the text field. Then on the basic page content type, i added a paragraph field.

Paragraph bundle fields:

1. text (field_text)
2. background color (field_bkg_clr) <-- the drop down list1

Basic Page content type:

1. Header (field_pr_hdr, which is of type paragraph)

Comment: You may take a look at this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_css_class. "The Field formatter CSS class module allows you to set any text/list/option/taxonomy field to render as CSS class on the node. This enables the node author to select predefined CSS styling per node." I guess this is what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Volker thank you for the quick response. I tried using the module and it did not provide what i was looking for. I have updated the description so that it is more detailed.

Comment: see the answer to [How can I alter variables sent to a paragraph bundle template within a module?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/160357/how-can-i-alter-variables-sent-to-a-paragraph-bundle-template-within-a-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the [Field Formatter CSS class](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_css_class) module for the same task. The client wanted to have predefined colors for heading elements in paragraph bundles. I have to admit this seems like an amendable approach, but it worked.

I had set up a vocabulary for the color names list and referenced this in the paragraph bundle as a select list (taxonomy term reference). In the display settings for the field is css-class selected. The format settings are set to target tag = entity.

This results basically in following markup:

```
<div class="entity entity-paragraphs-item paragraphs-item h1-colorclass-red">
    <div class="field-name-field-heading">This is a headline</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.h1-colorclass-red .field-name-field-heading {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I was able to use hook_prerender and hook_preprocess to take the values from the select list and using the "#prefix" and "#suffix" attribute to set the values.

Comment: yes that is a good option. Another option i found was to use hook_preprocess and hook_prerender to take the machine values of the select list and add it to the field using the "#suffix" and "#prefix" attributes

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with adding the classes to some wrapper all you need is [`hook_preprocess_HOOK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7.x).

This one adds the class retrieved from a select list field of the paragraph item to the paragraph item wrapper. I guess that's exactly what [Field Formatter CSS Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_css_class) is doing.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_entity(&$variables) {

  $my_field_name = 'field_MYSELECT';
  $my_paragraph_bundle = 'foo';

  $element = $variables['elements'];
  if ($element['#entity_type'] == 'paragraphs_item' && $element['#bundle'] == $my_paragraph_bundle) {
    foreach ($element[$my_field_name]['#items'] as $item) {
      $variables['classes_array'][] = $item['value'];
    }
  }
}
```